# How to collapse tabs in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using this Javascript script to display a list of Youtube channels related to a specific topic when this is chosen by the user, but if I click again on the name of the topic, its tab does not collapse.  Instead it again shows the list of channels.

```
var channels=[
    { id:1, name:"Example 1", description:"", videos:[]},
    { id:2, name:"Example 2", description:"", videos:[]},
];

jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#tabs").tabs();
    listChannels();
});

function listChannels(){
    jQuery(channels).each(function(i,channel){
        jQuery("#listOfChannels").append("<li id='channel"+channel.id+"'><span onclick='showChannel("+channel.id+")'>&gt; "+channel.name+"</span><div id='videos"+channel.id+"' class='contentChannel'></div></li>");
    });
}
```

Comment: maybe add a `select` option to tabs init and in that you could `hide` the tab..or maybe youre looking for Accordion - http://jqueryui.com/accordion/?

Comment: Writing inline `onclick` handlers via jQuery makes my eyes bleed.

Comment: @moonwave99 using `onclick` with `each`. its a lethal combo isnt it? length of array === no of seperate onclick handlers :D

Comment: @moonwave99 you better correct his code than making this kind of comments, you see that he is new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Collapsing a tab doesn't mean anything, do you mean changing the active tabs ? If yes, have you read the jquery ui tabs documentation and what is blocking you ? [enable()](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#method-enable) should be pretty straightforward

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly actually he signed up before me, and "correcting" that code is out of the scope of the question. Still, he may find useful reading about [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could try setting `collapsible: true` in your `tabs` init. See [Docs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#collapsible)

```
 $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
  collapsible: true
 });
```

But in your situation, i feel like its better to use [Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/), a better visual representation for your channels.

**AND**, as @moonwave99 mentioned, its not good to use `onclick` attribute, especially in a loop. [Read this question to know more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice). (Extras : [Docs for event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) ) Use `click` event handler which jquery provides.

```
$("#listOfChannels").on("click", "li" , function () {
   showChannel(this.id);
});
```

and, save your `listChannels()` from the evil clutches of `onclick`

```
jQuery(channels).each(function(i,channel){
    jQuery("#listOfChannels").append("<li id='channel"+channel.id+"'><span>&gt; "+channel.name+"</span><div id='videos"+channel.id+"' class='contentChannel'></div></li>");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this. Indeed it is a code that is already implemented by somebody else and I was told today to learn jQuery and solve that :(

Comment: Mark the answer as the correct answer if it helps you :-) learning jquery isn't that hard.. Docs are very good in jquery.com